# 64-bit fortran DLL

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, fortran

I want to write a DLL in fortran and call it in MATLAB (I use MATLAB 64-bit). 
It seems that MinGW and CygWin provides fortran 32-bit compilers and it is possible to create DLL using these compilers. But I'm not sure if the output DLLs can be used in MATLAB.
I do not want to go for Intel Fortran as it is too expensive.
I would like to know whether or not I must use a 64-bit fortran compiler.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your Matlab version. For example, Intel's [latest compiler](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-visual-fortran-composer-xe-evaluation) is not supported by Matlab 2012a (no surprise there), but  [Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-composer-xe-2011-release-notes) is. If you have a previous matlab version search for the list of Supported and Compatible Compilers, for example the list of Matalb 2012a is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012a/)...

Answer (score 1):

You may use Rtools (see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/)), the compilers used to build programs for the statistical package R. It has both 32 bit and 64 bit compilers (gcc toolchain).

**Edit**: gcc (including Ada, C, C++ and Fortran compilers) can be obtained from MinGW-builds on SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/